# Line break inside quotes in an HTML attribute?

Tags: html

I have this HTML:

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post"
   onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form? Submitting this form has serious consequences and you should definitely think long and hard before doing it.');">
```

I want to keep my code at or below 80 characters wide. How can I split this up into multiple lines while retaining the exact same functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ld create a Javascript section that defines a function that you call from the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
         return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form? Submitting' +
                        ' this form has serious consequences and you should ' +
                        'definitely think long and hard before doing it.');
    }
</script>
```

the form:

```
<form action="mypage.php" method="post" onsubmit="formSubmit()">
```

This gets your Javascript out of you HTML form and can be clearly broken where you like.

Answer (score 1):

Do as you want. It is not important to the HTML as long as you avoid doing this for blocks like `<PRE>`. There's lot of tools like HTML Tidy, HTML beautify, HTML format you could google for and try. Or hit ENTER by hand from time to time

**EDIT**

I seem to not really get the question at first. If you need to split the JS arguments, slice the strings into smaller blocks and then concatenate it back using `+`, so instead of

```
alert('long line here');
```

you cold write:

```
alert('long ' +
      'line ' +
      'here');
```

but it would be better to separate JS from HTML so your `onSubmit` should calling the function, instead of holding the end JS code.

Comment: I was assuming he meant in the confirmation box itself, when it pops up?

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer.

Comment: Good good. Wanted to make sure I didn't misread it myself :)

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely recommend removing the inline Javascript and keeping things separated. You could even go so far as to remove the `onsubmit` function and just capture the event in your Javascript itself.

You could break up the string and concatonate it again as has been proposed to get a quick solution, but if you would like to style the confirmation box even more, I would suggest looking into something like http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/boxy/ or http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation for additional solution options.